# Why Jest is not letting me use node testing environment even though they changed it themselves?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I am trying to test a React component in Next.js with Jest.

Jest [officially announced](https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27) that they are changing the default test environment to Node:

> For this reason, we are **changing the default test environment** from
> `"jsdom"` to `"node"`.

I need to use the Node environment and they are not letting me.

I am receiving the following error:

```
  ● basic test

    The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.
    
    ReferenceError: document is not defined

      40 | it("basic test", async () => {
      41 |   render(<Hellopage />);
    > 42 |   expect(true).toBe(true);
         |                 ^
      43 |   screen.debug();
      44 | });
      45 |

      at Object.render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:83:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (components/__test__/hellopage.test.tsx:42:17)
```

The reason I need to use node is that Firebase Firestore is not working under JSDOM.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It _is_ letting you use the Node environment. It's failing because that environment doesn't include definitions of things like `document`, which are part of the DOM API (and hence provided by JSDOM) and **not** in Node.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there a way for me to get these definitions and still use node, as the firebase require it for testing?

Comment: You'd have to provide them into the global scope for the tests yourself. Basically you'd be rewriting some subset of what JSDOM provides. It's unclear what specific problem you had that pushed you in this direction to begin with; you might be better off asking with a [mre] of that, this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I am using jsdom testing environment I get error : "FIRESTORE (9.1.3) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state".
Sorry, but im very lost, how come the default testing environment that jest comes with can't render the simple react component, what else are developers supposed to test it?

Comment: Because the default test environment is now Node, which is for... a Node environment. **Not** the DOM environment, which is where React (however simple a component) runs. Developers testing code for the DOM environment are supposed to use a testing environment that provides the DOM APIs, like JSDOM.

Comment: Or more broadly: they changed the default because not everyone who wants to test JavaScript code is using React, or the DOM at all (from the doc you quoted and I linked: _"Running tests in a JSDOM environment incurs a significant performance overhead... users who are writing Node apps, for example, may not even know they are given an expensive DOM environment that they do not even need"_).

Answer (score 0):

If you are unit testing a React component, you definitely need the jsdom testing environment. But what you're trying to achieve is to test the UI, not the database access. If you access external resources it's not unit testing anymore, it's integration testing.

What you want to do is to decouple the UI component from the database queries, so that your tests can provide fake data without hitting the database. Similarly if your component writes anything to the database, it could do it through a function that your tests are providing instead of the one you use in production.